# Modify git branch to be branched from upstream commit

Tags: git

I forked a git repository, branched `new_feature` from `master`, developed a new feature, and merged my branch back into `master`. Like so:

```
^
|
*     <-- current commit
|\
| \
*  *
*  |
|  *  <-- new_feature branch
|  |
*  *
| /
|/
*
*
*
|
*     <-- release commit on master
|
```

In hindsight, I wish I would have branched from `master` at the `release` commit. This is because master isn't quite clean and not all tests pass. So I wish I had:

```
^
|
*
*     <-- next commit on master after release commit
*
|
*
|\
| \
|  *
|  |
|  *  <-- new_feature branch
|  |
|  *
| /
|/
*     <-- release commit on master
|
```

Is this possible, and if so, how? I'm the only user working in `new_feature` and I've never committed to `master` previously, if that helps isolate commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible, but it's a **DISTRUCTIVE** history change, and you need to be careful with it.

let's first give the needed commits some dummy SHAs just to be able to identify them in git commands:

*Current state:*

```
^
|
*  F679B1B <-- current commit on master
|
*  11937F5 <-- merge commit
|\
| \
*  |  D2FD393
|  |
|  *  <-- 45C9A66  new-feature branch
|  |
*  |  91C021C
| /
|/
*  15B6BDD
|
*  A132263  <-- release commit on master
|
```

and the idea is to:

- make a copy of `master`:

```sh
git checkout master
git checkout -b second_master
```

- make a hard reset to the release commit on `master`:

```sh
git reset --hard A132263
```

- branch a new feature branch:

```sh
git checkout -b new-feature
```

- move your commits from the old feature branch to the new feature branch, one by one and in order:

```sh
git cherry-pick 45C9A66
```

- merger or issue a merge request to `seond-master` at release commit:

```sh
git checkout second-master
git merge new-feature
```

- get the other commits from the original `master`:

```sh
git cherry-pick 15B6BDD
git cherry-pick 91C021C
git cherry-pick D2FD393
git cherry-pick F679B1B
```

- check if the status of `second-master` is OK, then hard reset the original `master` to it
  (**CAREFUL DISTRUCTIVE COMMAND**: after this, the original `master` is lost and replaced with the `second-master`):

```sh
git checkout master
git reset --hard second-master
```

After these steps, you should have the following state in your git repo:

*Result state:*

```
^
|
* 75C70DB <-- current commit on master
|
|
* BC63DDC
|
| 
* 03042CF
|
|
* 019D5F6
|
* E3FAABE <-- merge commit
|\
| \
|  |
|  |
|  * <-- 45C9A66  new-feature branch
|  |
|  |
| /
|/
* A132263  <-- release commit on master
|
```

hope this helps give you the impression if that is worth it to be done or not, and direct you through the way.

Answer (score 1):

Two other options I can think of:

1. <s>If there weren't many commits between the release commit and the commit you branched off of,</s> You could revert each of those commits.
2. If you don't care about retaining the individual commits you made, you could soft reset master to where you branched off from it, stash those changes, hard reset to the release commit and apply the stash.

Two show you an example of the two options above, I've added fictional commit ids to your diagram:

```
^
|
* current-commit    <-- current commit
|\
| \
*  *
*  |
|  *  <-- new_feature branch
|  |
*  *
| /
|/
* commit-branched-off-of
* intermediate-commit-1
* intermediate-commit-2
|
* release-commit    <-- release commit on master
|
```

Option 1 could then be as simple as (if you don't get any conflicts):

```
git revert release-commit..commit-branched-off-of
```

The command above will revert all commits after `release-commit` up to and including `commit-branched-off-of`.

If you do get any conflicts, just follow the prompts to fix the conflicts.

Option 2 could be:

```
git reset --soft commit-branched-off-of
git stash
git reset --hard release-commit
git stash apply
git commit -m "New commit message for your feature"
```